# Using Mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with drush

Tags: 8, database

I want to able to load a huge CSV file directly into the database using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE like below:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Subscriber.csv' INTO TABLE temp_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS`

If I enter into the mysql via command line using `drush sql-cli` and run the command above I get;

`ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version`

After some research I found out that if you access mysql via the command line using the `--local-infile` flag, I can be able to use the LOAD DATA LOCAL. Below will be the statement that I use to get into mysql :

`mysql --local-infile -u root -p -h mysql`

Using the command above will make it possible for me to use LOAD DATA in mysql but i want to be able to use it with `drush sql-query`. How can I apply the `--local-infile` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`drush sql-query`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/sql/sql-query/) has a not-very-well documented option flag called `--extra`. This flag is used when [connecting via the `mysql` command](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/9.3.0/src/Sql/SqlBase.php#L124) to add extra options to the command string. So a `drush sql-query --extra '--local-infile'` should enable Drush to connect the client with your needed option.